# Using values in different activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to build an app which has a start screen with buttons leading to several different activities. In one of the  activities subsequent to the start screen I get int values which I would like to use in another subsequent activity. From what I've seen values usually get passed between activities using bundles and intents sort of like this:

> Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
>   AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
>   String getrec=textView.getText().toString();
>
> //Create the bundle
>   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
>
> //Add your data to bundle
>   bundle.putString(“stuff”, getrec);
>
> //Add the bundle to the intent
>   i.putExtras(bundle);
>
> //Fire that second activity
>   startActivity(i);

and adding this in the second:

> //Get the bundle
>   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
>
> //Extract the data…
>   String stuff = bundle.getString(“stuff”);

However I don't want my third activity to get started from the second one, is there a way to send a value without starting the other activity it is going to get used? If not should I pass the values to the start screen activity and from there to the other one and if so how?

Comment: There's a variety of ways depending on the type and size of data.  Singletons, shared preferences, files, databases, etc may all be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to store data in Android. Depending on the type of data different situations may apply:

#### 1. Shared Preferences

Stores data in key value pairs. Here's some code

Saving Values:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);
  editor.commit();
```

Retrieving values:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
```

#### 2. SQLite Databases

This is a relational database for storing information [Here's](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) a tutorial.

I've gone into detail on the two that apply in this case, but you can check out the rest over here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

> you can  declare public static variable and access it anywhere in app but its not a good practice try using . Another way is you can use sharedpreference to store that value

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you have data you want persisted throughout your application.

Read into an SQLite Database or a Realm Database.

I have more experience using Realm databases so that would be my choice.

https://sqlite.org/

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/